# Warn about name shadowing in scala 2.11

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings, compiler-flags

I'm using SBT to build a project and have in my `Build.scala`:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature", "-Xfatal-warnings")
```

How can I configure the project to warn on name/variable shadowing? I've browsed the source [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/StandardScalaSettings.scala) and [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/ScalaSettings.scala), but don't see what I'm looking for among the many options. A comment on [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031106/why-does-scala-support-shadow-variables) mentions a flag `-Ywarn-shadowing` which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Maybe someone knows about a scala-abide or wart remover for that. I don't see it off-hand. There are other use cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587965/scala-making-sure-that-a-field-from-the-superclass-is-used https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9100 https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4762

Comment: This covers the sentiment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385293/how-can-i-get-scalac-to-tell-me-if-i-have-unused-variables

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601372/how-can-i-find-a-description-of-scala-compiler-flags-options), you could start exploring with `-X`. I then tried `-Xlint:help` and this yields some settings for shadowing:

```
Information:scalac: Enable or disable specific warnings
  adapted-args               Warn if an argument list is modified to match 
                             the receiver.
  nullary-unit               Warn when nullary methods return Unit.
  inaccessible               Warn about inaccessible types in method signatures.
  nullary-override           Warn when non-nullary `def f()' overrides nullary 
                             `def f'.
  infer-any                  Warn when a type argument is inferred to be `Any`.
  missing-interpolator       A string literal appears to be missing an 
                             interpolator id.
  doc-detached               A ScalaDoc comment appears to be detached from its 
                             element.
  private-shadow             A private field (or class parameter) shadows a 
                             superclass field.
  type-parameter-shadow      A local type parameter shadows a type already in 
                             scope.
  poly-implicit-overload     Parameterized overloaded implicit methods are not 
                             visible as view bounds.
  option-implicit            Option.apply used implicit view.
  delayedinit-select         Selecting member of DelayedInit.
  by-name-right-associative  By-name parameter of right associative operator.
  package-object-classes     Class or object defined in package object.
  unsound-match              Pattern match may not be typesafe.
  stars-align                Pattern sequence wildcard must align with sequence 
                             component.
```

Probably `-Xlint:private-shadow` is what you want?

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but I was looking for shadowing of variables e.g. `val` in nested scopes, or a `val` shadowing a function or method argument. It looks like it might not be possible, which is a bit cuckoo to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are many scala linter tools. [Scapegoat](https://github.com/sksamuel/scapegoat) has an option for `VariableShadowing`. I don't see a shadowing option in the more popular linters, but you could implement one yourself.